# Duplicate and modify words in bash with sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm on Linux OS. I have a file to modify in my bash script.

My original file is like that:

```
...
ERIC-1898
HELENE-5456
THOMAS-54565
IRON-06516
...
```

And I'd like to modify this file with duplicate words (and `-SYSTEM-` word in second field), and add double quotes. 
So, the result has to be like that:

```
...
"ERIC-1898" "ERIC-SYSTEM-1898" 
"HELENE-5456" "HELENE-SYSTEM-5456"
"THOMAS-54565" "THOMAS-SYSTEM-54565"
"IRON-06516" "IRON-SYSTEM-06516"
...
```

How can I do that, for example with sed?

Comment: `sed -E 's/(.*)-(.*)/"&" "\1-SYSTEM-\2"/'`?

Comment: Yep it also works :-) thanks mate !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed and two capture groups:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*-\)\(.*\)/"&" "\1SYSTEM-\2"/' infile
"ERIC-1898" "ERIC-SYSTEM-1898"
"HELENE-5456" "HELENE-SYSTEM-5456"
"THOMAS-54565" "THOMAS-SYSTEM-54565"
"IRON-06516" "IRON-SYSTEM-06516"
```

Assuming that there is exactly one hyphen per input line.

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F'-' '{printf("\"%s\" \"%s-SYSTEM-%s\"\n", $1FS$2,$1,$2)}' file
```

The output would be like:

```
"ERIC-1898" "ERIC-SYSTEM-1898"
"HELENE-5456" "HELENE-SYSTEM-5456"
"THOMAS-54565" "THOMAS-SYSTEM-54565"
"IRON-06516" "IRON-SYSTEM-06516"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using external program:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'-'
while read -r first second;do
    echo "\"$first-$second\" \"$first-SYSTEM-$second\""
done <infile
```

Comment: You can make the `IFS` part of the loop instead of changing it globally: `while IFS='-' read -r first second; do`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/ /,"\" \"");print "\042" $0 "\042"}' file

"ERIC-1898" "ERIC-SYSTEM-1898"
"HELENE-5456" "HELENE-SYSTEM-5456"
"THOMAS-54565" "THOMAS-SYSTEM-54565"
"IRON-06516" "IRON-SYSTEM-06516"
```